# Maven project - server error 500 for me but works fine for someone else

Tags: maven

I have checked out a maven project which gives me a "`Return code is: 500, ReasonPhrase:Internal Server Error.`" when I try to compile it. Strangely though for a colleague exactly the same is working without problems. What can I do here?

**My Maven output**

```
autosparql-lite$ mvn clean compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building AutoSPARQL Lite 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://uk.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom
Downloaded: http://uk.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom (5 KB at 9.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://uk.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.jar
Downloaded: http://uk.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.jar (23 KB at 57.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://s1.semanticscience.org:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/com/extjs/gxt/2.2.5/gxt-2.2.5.pom
Downloading: http://s1.semanticscience.org:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/uk/ac/shef/wit/simmetrics/1.6.2/simmetrics-1.6.2.pom
Downloading: http://s1.semanticscience.org:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/woodstox/wstx-api/3.2.0/wstx-api-3.2.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.091s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Apr 12 15:45:28 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/209M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project autosparql-lite: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project org.dllearner:autosparql-lite:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: 
Failed to collect dependencies for [com.google.gwt:gwt-servlet:jar:2.3.0 (compile), com.google.gwt:gwt-user:jar:2.3.0 (provided), net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:pom:2.5.0 (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.8.1 (test), com.extjs:gxt:jar:2.2.5 (compile), org.dllearner:components-ext:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6 (compile)]: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.extjs:gxt:jar:2.2.5: 
Could not transfer artifact com.extjs:gxt:pom:2.2.5 from/to semanticscience.org (http://s1.semanticscience.org:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/): 
Failed to transfer file: http://s1.semanticscience.org:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/com/extjs/gxt/2.2.5    /gxt-2.2.5.pom. Return code is: 500, ReasonPhrase:Internal Server Error. -> [Help 1]
```

**My settings.xml**

```
<settings>
   <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>UK</id>
      <name>UK Central</name>
      <url>http://uk.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
</settings>
```

P.S.:

**My Maven version**

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (rNON-CANONICAL_2012-01-24_13-02_root; 2012-01-24 14:02:02+0100)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_03-icedtea, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.0.26-1-lts", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

**His Maven version**

```
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-4)
Java version: 1.7.0
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "2.6.38-13-generic" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"
```

P.S.: Can it have something to do with our maven versions? I use Maven 3 and he uses Maven 2. And where does this semanticscience server come from?

P.P.S.: Ok, I finally got rid of the semanticscience repository by deleting it from my pom.xml AND deleting the ~/.m2/repository folder. Now I get another error though, see below.

The strange thing is that the following urls are resolvable in a browser:

- [http://repo.aduna-software.org](http://repo.aduna-software.org/maven2/releases)
- http://repo.aduna-software.org/maven2/releases

However a ping does not work:

```
$ ping http://repo.aduna-software.org
ping: unknown host http://repo.aduna-software.org
$ ping http://repo.aduna-software.org/maven2/releases
ping: unknown host http://repo.aduna-software.org/maven2/releases
```

It's not the ping's fault though:

```
$ ping www.google.de
PING www-cctld.l.google.com (173.194.69.94) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from bk-in-f94.1e100.net (173.194.69.94): icmp_req=1 ttl=48 time=13.3 ms
[...]
```

Here is the error:

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-sail-memory:jar:2.4.0: Could not transfer artifact org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-sail-memory:pom:2.4.0 from/to aduna-software-release-repo (http://repo.aduna-software.org/maven2/releases): repo.aduna-software.org: Der Name oder der Dienst ist nicht bekannt: Unknown host repo.aduna-software.org: Der Name oder der Dienst ist nicht bekannt
```

I tried what `http://wiki.tuxtorials.de/wiki/Ping:_unknown_host` told me and did

```
echo "echo \"hosts:      files dns\" > /etc/nsswitch.conf" | sudo sh
```

But that didn't help either.

Ok I have no idea why but now it worked for me. But I would like to know why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have configured a Maven proxy somewhere, with name `http://s1.semanticscience.org:8080/nexus/`

Probably in one of your settings.xml file, either in `$HOME/.m2` or `$MAVEN_HOME/conf/`.

Comment: Nope :-( `~$ locate settings.xml | xargs grep semanticscience` -> no output

Comment: Do you have any authentication on the nexus server ?

Comment: I tried to connect here : http://s1.semanticscience.org:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/com/extjs/gxt/2.2.5 and I got the error 500. Your colleague probably already have the artifact in his local repository. And the Nexus server seems to be misconfigured.

Comment: No, my colleague does not get this error even if he deletes the package in his local repository. I have no idea where this semanticscience nexus server comes from.

Comment: It may comes from a pom.xml of one your dependencies. Try this `locate pom.xml | xargs grep semanticscience`

Comment: Ah yes you are right! The strange thing is, even if I comment out or remove the dependency, it is still used! Now that I deleted the repository folder in my .m2 folder, it finally seems to use the changed pom.xml but I have no idea why it would be cached in the repository folder... Now I get another error though :-( - see my edited original post.

Comment: Please close this question and ask a new one.

Comment: But I still don't know **why** removing the repository entry did not work and **why** I had to remove the repository directory.

Comment: Take a look at this for an explanation : https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-CachingofArtifactResolutionErrors

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the Nexus server replied with an error 500 when Maven tried to retrieve gxt-2.2.5 from there. I would just try again and if it still doesn't work, check the URL in your browser and maybe speak to the admin(s) of that Nexus installation.

Comment: Well I tried several times now and it never worked for me. However for my coleague the problem did not occur.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to download `com.extjs:gxt:pom:2.2.5` from http://s1.semanticscience.org:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/com/, but it's not available at that Nexus repo..

I suspect your colleague must be retrieving that artifact from another repository, but you are not.. Look into any additional repositories that he may have configured, or that you are leaving out.

Comment: We have **exactly** the same files.